# Jquery html insert on last

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have to add a code in html using Jquery html(), the problems is i need to add it on last element.My current Html will look as follow:

```
<div class="column column-sub-alpha " id="user_reviews_list">
  <div id="review_lister_header">
    <h3 id="recentReviews">Recent Reviews</h3>
      <p class="formNote">
      <a href="#">2 Reviews</a>
      </p>
  </div>
        <!-- need to add here from Jquery -->
</div>
```

my jquery code will look as follow:

```
var userReviewHtml = '<p>Hello</p>';
$('#user_reviews_list').html(userReviewHtml);
```

When i use `html()` my div with id `review_lister_header` is missing although it append correctly. How can i overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `append`:

```
$('#user_reviews_list').append(userReviewHtml);
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it... iPhones are too slow.

Answer (score 0):

`html()` method replaces all the inner html of element. USe `append()` to insert at end of element

API refrence: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

You should use append to add a new element to end:

```
$('#user_reviews_list').append(/*your new element*/);
```